# What is $X$ in the fundamental equation of factor analysis?

Tags: factor-analysis

Mulaik (2009) p. 135-136 writes that

> Let Y be an $n \times 1$ random vector of random variables whose
>   variables are the observed random variables $Y_{1}, ... , Y_{n}$.
>   Assume that $E(Y) = 0$ and that $E(YY′) = R_{YY}$ is a correlation
>   matrix with unities for the variances in its principal diagonal. Let
>   $X$ be an $r × 1$ random vector whose variables are the common
>   factors, $X_{1}, ... , X_{r}$. Assume that $E(X) = 0$ and $E(XX′) = R_{XX}$ is a correlation matrix, i.e., common factors have means of
>   zero and variances of unity. Next let $E$ be an $n × 1$ random vector
>   whose variables are the unique factors $ε_{1}, … , ε_{n}$, having the
>   property that $E(E) = 0$ and $E(EE′) = I$; that is, the unique factors
>   are normalized to have means of zero and variances of unity and are
>   mutually uncorrelated. Finally, let $\Lambda$ be an $n × r$ matrix of
>   common factor-pattern coefficients and $\Psi$ an $n × n$ diagonal
>   matrix of unique factor-pattern coefficients whose diagonal elements
>   are $ψ_{1}, ... ,ψ_{n}$.
>
> Then $Y = \Lambda X + \Psi E$ (fundamental equation of factor
>   analysis)

Just thinking about the first part of the equation, the observed variables and common factor-pattern coefficients are intuitive to me. However, I'm having trouble understanding what $X$ is meant to be.

I get that if I multiply $X$ by the transpose of itself a correlation matrix should result. But I don't understand what that correlation matrix would mean, what $X$ is or how it could be obtained in any particular scenario. What does it mean for something to be a vector of the common factors?

I don't really understand $\Psi$ or $E$ either, though I am hoping that if $X$ is explained then they might become self-explanatory.

Mulaik, S. A. (2009). Foundations of factor analysis. Chapman and Hall/CRC.

Comment: This is the standard notation for the so-called common factor model: $Y_1, \dots, Y_n$ are the observed variables, $X_1, \dots, X_r$ ($r < n$, usually) are the common factors which are linearly related to the observed variables (as described by the loading matrix, $\Lambda$). The diagonal elements of $\Psi$ are the weights or specific loadings of the unique factors $\varepsilon_1, \dots, \varepsilon_n$ (i.e., those specific of a particular variable).